# how can Cauchy-Schwarz help here?

Tags: probability-inequalities

From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004544/if-mathrme-x2-exists-then-mathrme-x-also-exists

> If $\mathrm{E} |X|^2$  is finite, then $\mathrm{E} X$  exists and is finite, because   $$ \mathrm{E} X  \leq \mathrm{E} |X| \leq  \sqrt{\mathrm{E} |X|^2} $$ by Jensen's inequality.

Someone said

> Why do you use Jensen's inequality, what about Cauchy-Schwarz?

I wonder how Cauchy-Schwarz can help? Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000681/15941) on math.SE for a proof via the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. The result can also be proved more simply as in [this other answer to the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000704/15941) or in drhab's and Michael Hardy's answers to your question on math.SE.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Can C-S be proved by Jensen's inequality?